# Wi-Fi issues on 17.04 - not sure why or how to fix

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, 17.04

After fiddling with Wi-Fi settings after problems, I've managed to get my Wi-Fi slower and cutting out after some usage. I know the problem is specific to my own computer, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I have tried `sudo service network-manager restart` with some help. I tried the `C -lshw` thing (have momentarily forgotten lol) and don't have it now, but can definitely do it again to get my Wi-Fi back to normal!

Sometimes my Wi-Fi works well enough to do simple things like right now, but it isn't sustainable or fast.
Any help would be appreciated!